# Obtener fechas en Python por una semana

Tags: python, bug

En el lenguaje python, usando DataBricks, estoy intentando tomar las fechas por semana En dataBricks se creo un widget llamado "carga", la cual tiene la "S" de Semana, despues usando Python, en un condicional if, si el widget tiene "S" debe mostrar la fecha de ayer y la fecha de hace una semana

Al intentar aparece este error

````
``` if(TipoCarga == 'S'):
    fechaproceso = dt_MX.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
    
    week = fechaproceso - datetime.timedelta(days = 1); //Error en esta linea
    day_week = week - datetime.timedelta(days = 7);
    
    
    
    fechaini = day_week.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    fechafin = week.strftime("%Y%m%d") ```
````

El mensaje de error es:

````
```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'```
````

Y el resultado debe ser algo asi

Ejemplo de resultado:
20230130
20230206

Comment: strfrime convierte una fecha en cadena. No lo hagas, pues después no podrás ya operar con ella como fecha (restarle otra fecha o sumarle timedeltas)

Comment: Viendo que ya migraron de meta tu pregunta original, votaré esta versión como duplicada así nos quedamos con la migrada.